# jQuery error with a menu-item link anchor: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code throws Syntax error, unrecognized expression: when in wordpress I have a menu-item with custom url with an anchor like: http://example.com/#contact

It's a code from a menu, animated with jQuery and the line causing the error is

`if (jQuery(id).isOnScreen()) {`

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery(".pagenav.home .menu > li:first-child a").addClass('important_color');
   if (jQuery(".menu-fixedmenu").length) {
     jQuery(".menu-fixedmenu.home .menu a").each(function() {
       var id = jQuery(this).attr('href');
       if (id.search("#") != -1) {
         jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
           if (jQuery(id).isOnScreen()) {
             jQuery(id + ' h2').removeClass('fadeInDown');
             jQuery(id + ' h2').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
             var newid = id.split("#");
             if (document.getElementById(newid[1]).getBoundingClientRect().top < 250) {
               jQuery(".fixedmenu .menu > li a[href='" + id + "']").addClass('important_color');
             } else {
               jQuery(".fixedmenu .menu > li a[href='" + id + "']").removeClass('important_color');
             }

           } else {
             if (id != jQuery(".menu > li:first-child a").attr('href'))
               jQuery(".fixedmenu .menu > li a[href='" + id + "']").removeClass('important_color');
             if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 700)
               jQuery(".menu-fixedmenu.home .menu > li:first-child a").removeClass('important_color');
             else
               jQuery(".menu-fixedmenu.home .menu > li:first-child a").addClass('important_color');

             jQuery(id + ' h2').removeClass('fadeInUp');
             jQuery(id + ' h2').addClass('animated fadeInDown');
           }

         });
       }
     });
   }
 });
```

I'm almost sure the problem is that this line `var id  = jQuery(this).attr('href');` it fills id variable with a full url with an anchor and when it calls the function isOnScreen() then it throws error. 
By the way, the code of the function:

```
jQuery.fn.isOnScreen = function(){

    var win = jQuery(window);

    var viewport = {
        top : win.scrollTop(),
        left : win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));

};
```

Any hint would be apreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with complete code.

Comment: How can I do that? It's a js from a Wordpress template. I can post all the js code, but I don't know how to put all the css and html in a jsfiddle..